# How to force using mobile version in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, user-agent

i want to force WebBrowser control open a website with mobile interface in Windows Phone 8 App. I have tried this but it not work

`string header = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0)";`

`webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(link, UriKind.Absolute), null, header);`